# Warning against C++ implicit conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int64_t> vec = {4294967296, 4294967296, 4294967296};
  int64_t sum = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, [](int64_t sum, int64_t val){
    return sum + val;
  });
  cout << "sum = " << sum << endl;
}
```

It returns `sum = 0` because implicit conversion from `int` to `int64` (see `0` as third argument of `accumulate` function). After replacing `0` with `(int64_t)0` everything works fine.

But can I detect such things in compile time? `-Wconversion` does not work in this case.

Comment: Catching cases such as that is very hard, and you might need a dedicated static analyzer to (possibly) catch it. The simple solution is not to use C-style casting (which is almost always a sign of you doing something wrong) but to use the `ll` suffix to tell the compiler that the value is a `long long int`. As in `0ll`.

Comment: Thanks. But can I pass some flag to compiler to prevent code like in example? Of cause if I know about conversion I can fix it

Comment: Can you specify which compiler you are using please?

Comment: @JackAidley Only GCC support -Wconversion

Comment: Finally I found an easy way to get the warning message from system header files.

Comment: I used clang. It seems clang supports -Wconversion because it warn in more simple cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code of `std::accumulate` were not in a system header file, you would get the warning:

```
int init=0;
init += *vec.begin() //warning: conversion from 'int64_t' {aka 'long int'} to 'int' may change value [-Wconversion]
```

But many warnings are disabled for system header files because such warning would cause many noisy and irrelevant messages.

This behavior can be reproduced. Suppose you have this file `test.hpp`:

```
int64_t i;
int j = i;
```

If you compile a file `test.cpp` in the same directory that includes this file:

- with `c++ -I . test.cpp -Wconversion`, the warning message is printed;
- with `c++ -isystem . test.cpp -Wconversion` the *warning message* is *not printed*!

This is exactly what happens to header files of the standard library, the include directory is by default specified with `-isystem`.

The system header warning message suppression can be disabled with option `-Wsystem-header`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/spx1z3)

And it can be seen on the *Demo* the warning message is hidden within a bunch or irrelevant warning messages.